# Horizontally centering elements inside a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

To make this easy, say you had a div that was 100px wide, and 3 divs inside of it each 20px wide.  How can I align them to where they align to the center of the div leaving a 20px; gap on each side?

Comment: to make it even more easy you can post a JSFiddle

Comment: Is anything known ahead of time other than the size of the parent div? Are the actual child divs variable-width? Is there a variable number of child divs?

Answer (score 4):

Center some HTML elements always depends of your project and integration dependencies...

You may be happy with these 2 solutions, display: inline-block; and float: left;

Both have pros & cons, hope that it can help you !

http://jsfiddle.net/HP2DS/1/

```
<!-- Inline-block -->
<div id='container'>
    <div class='centered' id='content-left'></div><div class='centered' id='content-center'></div><div class='centered' id='content-right'></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    background: cyan;
}

#container .centered {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: magenta;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

<!-- Floating -->
<div id='container-2'>
    <div class='centered' id='content-2-left'></div>
    <div class='centered' id='content-2-center'></div>
    <div class='centered' id='content-2-right'></div>
</div>

#container-2 {
    width: 60px; /* 60px + 2*20px of padding... */
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: cyan;
}

#container-2 .centered {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: magenta;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good day! Here is how I implemented it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red; /** for viewing purposes **/
  text-align: center; /** center the divs **/
  font-size: 0; /** remove the unwanted space caused by display: inline-block in .child **/
}

#container .child {
  display: inline-block; /** set the divs side-by-side **/
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 12px; /** override font-size: 0 of #container, so that text will be visible again **/
  text-align: left; /** set text in the .child divs back to normal alignment **/
  border: 1px solid blue; /** for viewing purposes **/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I hope this helps. Cheers! :)